# How to pass onClick from view pager to view below it?

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager

I have view pager above tablayout, as some pages have to hide tablayout, but now I cannot click on my tabs.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dip"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      app:tabBackground="@drawable/bg_tab"
      app:tabGravity="fill"
      app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
      app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dip"
      app:tabMinWidth="0dip"
      app:tabMode="fixed"
      app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
      app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
      app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
      />
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/view_pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"

      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use `yourView.bringToFront()`..!!

Comment: What you want exactly?

Comment: @jankigadhiya bring to front works well, post it is an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `yourView.bringToFront()`.

[bringToFront](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront())

> Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling
>   views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container
>   uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). Prior to
>   KITKAT this method should be followed by calls to requestLayout() and
>   invalidate() on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw with
>   the new child ordering.